# Forwarding emails via the Mailgun API: possible?

Tags: email, mailgun

I have a use case for an email flow that looks something like this:

- 1) User sends an email to a specified address
- 2) Service receives the email and pings a webhook with the email in json format
- 3) My webhook/backend runs a quick check on the sender's email address and either:
- 4a) Creates an email and sends it as a reply to the original user, or
- 4b) Forwards the original email to another destination (it's important that the forward email retains the original senders address/reply-to etc.

Ok, I can easily get as far as 4a) using one of a few services (PostmarkApp, Mailgun, etc), but I'm struggling with 4b) - forwarding using an API.

The closest I can get is to receive the email into my Mailgun account and set a route that both stores it, and pings a webhook URL.

It then seems like I should be able to instruct Mailgun to forward the stored email to the final destination - but I just can't figure it out.

Anyone been here before?

I'm asking here before trying Mailgun support.

Thanks.

Comment: I am looking to send an email to an address of mine and get MailGun to send a POST request to a URL. Did you get something similar working in the end?

Comment: Were you able to find how this works?